# Username maximum length in Devise 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to save a new password, I get an error that a user's username is too long (I'm using the [username mechanism for Devise with Rails 3.2.x here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)). How do I increase the length a username can be? I didn't see anything about this in `devise.rb`.

```
irb(main):002:0> u.password='resetpass'
=> "resetpass"
irb(main):003:0> u.password_confirmation='resetpass'
=> "resetpass"
irb(main):005:0> u.save!
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('exterminator5000') AND "users"."id" != 128) LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Username must have at most 15 characters
```

Comment: This isn't being caused from a custom validation in your user model?

Comment: Could you show user model?

Comment: @smefju and trh - it was actually the `User` model, if you put that as an answer, I'll give you the win

Comment: @at. done :). Check below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in your `User` model. Take a look on this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length. You should change `length` validation for this field.

Answer (score 0):

```
 validates :username, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
```

`Add` this line of code in your `User Model` then it will validate to atleast `50 characters`.